# SIgnificant P-Value with overlapping boxplots

Tags: r, p-value, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, boxplot

I'm confused about some of the results I got after plotting my data.

I have a data set that includes tests scores and a binary group assignment of either polypharmacy or non-polypharmacy. the scores are unpaired. I have 132 overall observation with 35 being non-polypharmacy.

Here is a reproducible example of my data:

`structure(list(MOCA = c(11, 11, 14, 13, 10, 11, 12, 16, 6, 13,  12, 10, 14, 4, 5, 8, 7, 13, 5, 12, 14, 7, 15, 8, 11, 12, 14,  16, 3, 10, 16, 9, 7, 14, 14, 10, 4, 12, 16, 12, 13, 5, 12, 9,  13, 11, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 12, 9, 11, 14, 10, 2, 14, 16, 16,  13, 9, 13, 11, 12, 12, 16, 14, 12, 7, 13, 14, 11, 13, 16, 13,  14, 6, 10, 11, 13, 14, 9, 16, 13, 16, 8, 12, 12, 11, 11, 12,  14, 11, 14, 6, 11, 13, 12, 12, 12, 1, 14, 16, 9, 16, 10, 12,  16, 13, 6, 11, 17, 11, 13, 9, 14, 13, 13, 14, 14, 13, 4, 7, 12,  13, 12, 14, 16, 14, 13, 14), Group = c("Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy", "Polypharmacy",  "Non-Polypharmacy", "Non-Polypharmacy")), class = c("rowwise_df",  "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -132L), groups = structure(list( .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L,  10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L,  21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L,  32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L,  43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L,  54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L,  65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L,  76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L,  87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L,  98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L,  108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L,  117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L,  126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of",  "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -132L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame")))`

I used `Wilcox.test` to test the significances with produced the following results:

Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  MOCA by Group
**W = 2338, p-value = 0.0008804**
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
0.9999611 2.9999549
sample estimates:
difference in location
1.999979
So according to this test, my results are indeed significant but i wanted to visually confirm using a box plot so I plotted the data and found that both plots overlap quite a bit. Here is the box plot in question:

[image: Box Plot of Data]

Could some enlighten me as to what is going on?? Are my results valid (if so,  is there a some way i can prove it?)? Did I do something wrong? Any advice/insights would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why do you think this is a problem?

Comment: Overlap isn't dispositive.  At https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/87096/919 I performed an analysis of whether and how you can use boxplot comparisons to conduct valid tests when the underlying distributions are continuous (that is, ties are not possible).

Answer (score 3):

This broadens the discussion to ask whether you're focusing on one question -- the comparison of overall levels -- when other questions arise that seem as or possibly even more important.

The boxplots do hint strongly at most of what I am going to say, but with a dataset like this there is no reason not to plot all the data. So, here are dotplots or stripplots presented as Lego-style histograms. They make more evident the difference in both spread and skewness.

I show boxplots too but the Tukey convention about separately plotting points more than 1.5 IQR away from the nearer quartile doesn't seem compelling if you can see all the data. The convention arose when Tukey was focusing on hand-drawn plotting and being parsimonious about how much you plotted. 50 years on from that, we don't need to follow suit.

Beyond that, a common weakness of box plots is under-emphasising the 50% of values that are outside the boxes, likely to seem every bit as interesting or important as the 50% inside the boxes.

Is there a threshold or cut-off at 17? Nobody got more.

The question to me from this is not whether there is a systematic shift between groups -- which in a fairly strong sense can be answered yes -- but how to think about the different tails towards lower values.

I didn't feel the urge to use R here. No doubt you could do something very similar in R.

[image]

Comment: My reading of your plots is that there is probably a group of people who are unaffected by polypharmacy but there is (as you hint) a tail whose cognitive scores (assuming that is what MOCA is here) have been depressed. Neat plots.

Comment: @mdewey Thanks for the compliment. What's polypharmacy any way? Using many drugs? Is a high score good or bad? These are perhaps questions for the OP.

Comment: Yes, polypharmacy is taking many prescribed drugs. It is particularly common in older people. Since drugs often interact it can be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The null hypothesis tested by the Wilcoxon test is that the two distributions are equal, against the alternative (informally stated) that one tends to produce larger values than the other. Note that the alternative does *not* mean that *all* values produced by one distribution are larger than *all* values produced by the other distribution. Consider for example a die that produces 1,2,3,4,5,6 with probability of $\frac{1}{6}$ each, and another one, loaded, that rolls a 6 with probability $\frac{3}{8}>\frac{1}{6}$ and the other numbers with probability $\frac{1}{8}<\frac{1}{6}$ each. The two distributions are not equal, and the second die clearly has a tendency to produce larger numbers (more precisely, it will show a 6 more often). So with a large enough sample size the Wilcoxon test should reject the null hypothesis that the two distributions are equal, yet they are strongly overlapping; it may well happen that the first die shows a 5 and the second one a 2.

Also the two boxplots you have, for the given sample size, show clearly enough that the two distributions are not equal, and that the non-polypharmacy group tends to produce larger values. Therefore it makes sense that Wilcoxon rejects equality. (In fact the highest score is apparently observed in the polypharmacy group, but this doesn't change the fact that overall a far larger percentage of the higher values is in the non-polypharmacy group.)